# What is the the correct treatment while short for the cash in lieu of a reverse split?

Tags: corporate-actions

Long case:

- Assume I am Long 50 shares and there is a 2 for 3 reverse split.
- Let's denote the quantity of stock by x
- Prior to the split Portfolio is  $-cash_0$ $+50x$
- I am then at $-cash_0 +33x +\frac{1}{3}x$  after the split
- The $\frac{1}{3}x$ is converted into cash with proceeds $P$ known as cash in lieu
- so $cash_1 = -cash_0 + P$

Now for the short case:

- I sell 50 shares of x and receive proceeds $+cash_0$
- So my portfolio is $+cash_0$ $-50x$
- Assume I am short 50 shares and there is a 2 for 3 reverse split, so I have my $+cash_0$, I Owe $-33x$ and the one third when I am long would have turned into cash in lieu
- My portfolio is $+cash_0 -33x -\frac{1}{3}x$

What is the treatment of the $-\frac{1}{3}x$ ?

Is $+cash_1 = cash_0-P$ ?

When is it paid back? Is it treated similar to a dividend while short?

Comment: You should add a bit of formatting to get the question more readable and understandable. Because this might seem very clear to you but it's quite difficult to read.

Comment: Added formatting and tried to clarify

Comment: Can you please also edit the title so that it becomes a question?